# Focus lost to "Always on Visible Workspace" window when switching desktops

Tags: gnome, multiple-monitors, workspaces, external-monitor, workspace-switcher

I'm on Ubuntu 23.04 on my laptop with an extra monitor. I have Slack on the laptop screen as an "Always on Visible Workspace" window, and on the extra monitor I have 2 separate windows of vscode in 2 separate workspaces.

When I'm typing in vscode windoow #1 and switch to the next workspace (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>←</kbd>) the window focus goes to the slack window in the other monitor instead of staying in the current monitor and going to vscode windoow #2 in the next workspace, which is what I expect.

How could I fix this?